# Blazor not loaded SSL in browser

Tags: c#, ssl, blazor, .net-6.0

I have to install blazor wep app on one of the servers, which also has installed ssl certificate. I have thumbprint and when I search certificate it has been found, but when I run app and try to open the page says like page can not be found, but if I use http instead of https it is working. Why my code do not use ssl certificate if it is founded ?
Here is code how I'm loading ssl:

```
    var certThumbPrint = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
var certificate = GetCertificateByThumbprint(certThumbPrint);

if (certificate != null)
{
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel((context, options) =>
    {

        options.ListenAnyIP(5001, delegate (ListenOptions listenOptions)
        {
            listenOptions.UseHttps(
                httpsOptions =>
            {
                var localhostCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                    "localhost", "My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                    allowInvalid: true);
                var exampleCert = CertificateLoader.LoadFromStoreCert(
                    "*.example.com", "My", StoreLocation.LocalMachine,
                    allowInvalid: true);

                var certs = new Dictionary<string, X509Certificate2>(
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                {
                    ["localhost"] = localhostCert,
                    ["test.example.com"] = exampleCert,
                };

                httpsOptions.ServerCertificate = certificate;

                httpsOptions.ServerCertificateSelector = (connectionContext, name) =>
                {
                    if (name is not null && certs.TryGetValue(name, out var cert))
                    {
                        return cert;
                    }

                    return exampleCert;
                };
            });
        });
    });
}
X509Certificate2? GetCertificateByThumbprint(string thumbprint)
{
    using var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
    var certificateCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
        X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, validOnly: false);

    return certificateCollection.Count > 0 ? certificateCollection[0] : null;
}
```

Comment: Code looks fine. Is the certificate you are using is trusted by the client machine's browser?

Comment: Yes, and some other applications are using and opening without a problem, but they are already published to IIS, and currently I'm running this app from VS for some tests...

Comment: I guess the IIS is configured as proxy with the SLL certifcat, or? And the browser's developer console doesnt prompt any error messages, or?

Comment: In IIS they create website and immediately set SSL certificate with selecting one. But this I need to install as windows service, but I'm not sure if will work with SSL or not. To answer on second question , console do not prompt any error message.

Comment: I figure out one think, when I create windows service from app, certificate is working. Only from development env do not want to load SSL... :/

Comment: HTTPS uses TLS for encryption.  The TLS is sent before the HTTP request is sent and if TLS fails then the connection never completes.  Since connection doesn't complete you  will never get "page not found".  Normally when TLS fails you get a timeout since you will not get back a response.  So "page not found" may actually mean the connection never completed.  TLS the certificate must be loaded on both client and server before request is sent.  Server sends a certificate block with names of certificates than client searches the stores for a matching certificate.

Comment: The question's title is wrong. The code you posted doesn't send any certificates to the browser, it configures the Kestrel web server to use a specific certificate for HTTPS. You don't need all that code either, you can configure the certificate in `appsettings.json` [the way the docs show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0#replace-the-default-certificate-from-configuration). Have you tried this?

Comment: The code you used is needed only if you want your service to handle *multiple* HOST headers and use different certificates for different hosts. You don't need that in any other case, you could use a single certificate, specified in `appsettings`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos probably you are right about title. But I can not use appsettings.json as suggested in example, because client only provide thumbprint , but for sure I can use appsettings.json in order to store there thumbprint, it will be easier to change when cert expire.

Comment: HTTPS has nothing to do with thumbprints

Comment: No one said it has...

Comment: @jdweng May I ask you for small help ? How I can check if TLS is loaded on bot side before request is sent ?

Comment: See : https://gavilan.blog/2020/08/18/blazor-using-a-self-signed-certificate-for-identityserver4-in-azure-app-service/